# Is it possible to protect Facebook page from takeover by other administrator?

Tags: facebook, security

If many people have admin access to Facebook page one of them can delete page, or remove other administrator.

Is it possible to protect from that situation in some way (ie. master admin or password)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook used to restrict the original creator of the page from deletion, but removed that feature a few months ago.

So, no, there's no master password or anything protecting against the situation you present.

Comment: Facebook did recently announce at their last marketing conference that user permission roles for pages will be coming. ETA was supposed to be the end of March, 2012. :\
http://www.insidefacebook.com/2012/03/02/facebook-to-create-different-levels-of-access-for-page-admins/

Comment: +1 I wasn't aware of the page level permissions. I just checked one of the pages I created and have multiple admins on and it seems like the page-level perms aren't available yet.